# Animated text-align change in Safari issue

Tags: css, animation, safari

I use CSS keyframes and animation to animate `text-align`, but the animation of this property won't "play" in Safari, but the color of text does change.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  animation: ani 5s 1 both linear;
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
abcd
</div>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-water-6x2lq?fontsize=14)

Maybe it's a Safari bug because I can set the text-align: center to the div.

Comment: you cannot animate text-align property,

Comment: run his code snippet, that animation for text-align property is working.

Comment: @VSM use safari? and the text-align is working?

Comment: @Qyellow, Could you apply this to you styles. -webkit-animation: ani 5s 1 both linear;

Comment: @VSM it has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `browser prefix` will helps you. Tested safari `5.1.7`

```css
    .abcz {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-animation: ani 5s 1 both linear;
          animation: ani 5s 1 both linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ani {
  0% {
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    text-align: right;
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="abcz">
abcd
</div>
```

Comment: i tried your code

regretfully has no effect.

the color can be change but others can not

Comment: without animation using `text-align: -webkit-center` works. But with animation not working. Maybe it's problem with safari.

Comment: yeah,i think so.without animation, text-align: center also works

Comment: @Qyellow you could use `transform` instead of `text-align`.

Comment: yeah i know transform, but there are two problems.first, the text-align animation in other browsers is discontinuous, at right, left or center, but transform is continuous animation, behavior different. second, the text-decoration is the same, looks does't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the effect you're trying to get, but you could animate the position

```css
.abcz {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.animated {
  position: absolute;
  animation: ani 5s 1 both linear;
}

@keyframes ani {
  0% {
    color: red;
    left: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="abcz">
<div class="animated">abcd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, but you can see from the code you gave, underline is not working. For the sake of intuition, my problem is only text align. In fact, I want to know whether Safari will work on some attributes or not, because I have many attributes (at least text align, line height, text decoration)

Comment: according to this list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties
text-decoration can be animated but it doesn't seem to work on safari.

Comment: thank for you doc.actually i test line-height, can be animated but doesn't work on safari